# get Registered services in a subscription in Azure RM subscription using rest api

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How to find get a list of registered service in subscription in azure RM using below API we are able to get total service list ,but it's to large but i need a registered service list only

GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers?api-version=2018-02-01

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that we can't get filtered result with [Providers - List API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/providers/list#provider) directly. According to [Providers - List API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/providers/list#provider), it **doesn't supported** $filter. And I also test it on my side.

```
GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers?$top={$top}&$expand={$expand}&api-version=2018-02-01
```

My workaround is that we could filter the result as we expected based on returned json result. Or we could implement the filter function in our custom WebApp API.

If powershell command is possible we could use the snippet code:

```
Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ListAvailable | Where-Object {$_.RegistrationState -eq 'Registered'}
```

You also could give your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) to azure team.

Comment: Thanks for your response